# How to make client talk to server in same node proccess?

Tags: php, javascript, node.js

I have an application written in SSJS (Node) ... This application needs to serve data to the php script that will request by fsockopen .. All right here ... This server needs to collect data from a second server through a persistent connection. How to do this? Making the same process coordinate these connections? Is this possible?

```
var net         = require('net');
/*  #############################################
    #  "CLIENT" Used to connect to data server
    #   --------------------------------- 
    #############################################
*/

var clientConnect   = net.createConnection(port, host);
clientConnect.setEncoding('utf8');

clientConnect.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('Client','Connected to CAGEAPI');
    clientConnect.write('user@pass');
});

clientConnectt.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('Client','Data received: ' + data);
});

clientConnect.on('close', function(code) {
    console.log('Client','Connection closed');
});

clientConnect.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});


/*  ################################################
    #                                
    #  "SERVER" Used to serv data to PHPScripts 
    #   --------------------------------        
    ################################################
*/
var handleServer = net.createServer(function(server) {
    console.log('Server','CONNECTED: ' + server.remoteAddress +':'+ server.remotePort);
    server.on('data', function(data) {

        console.log('Server','DATA ' + server.remoteAddress + ': ' + data);
        // Write the data back to the socket, the client will receive it as data from the server
        server.write('You said "' + data + '"');

    });

    // Add a 'close' event handler to this instance of socket
    server.on('close', function(data) {
        console.log('Server','CLOSED: ' + server.remoteAddress +' '+ server.remotePort);
    });

}).listen(port2, host2);
```

Both (Client and server) is working fine... But how to make they talk each other?

Comment: You'll want to move the client creation code to the server's `connection` event handler (the function you are passing to `net.createServer()`), and attach the two peers' streams together using `.pipe()` - you'll need to do this in both directions if you want to act as a proxy enabling full duplex communication directly between the peers with no other involvement from Node. However, the thought occurs that this may be an unnecessary complication - can't you just connect directly from PHP to the remote host? Or did I miss something/

Comment: Ty bout your comment... I cant connect directly becouse the data server demands persistent connection handler... They dont allow more then one connection by same IP..

Comment: They ask me to made an Python or C++ aplication to handle this scenario... but Ill try to make it with js

Comment: How do you want to distribute the data between multiple PHP clients? Will a PHP client connect, retrieve all data since the last client connected and then disappear? Or do you want to potentially distribute the same data from the data source to more than one client?

Comment: Yep.. PHP connects get the data then disconnect

Comment: So it's not possible for more than one PHP client to be connected at once?

Comment: Its possible... Many clients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're probably after something like this:

```
/*jslint node: true, white: true */

// Declare constructors
var DataSource, PHPClientServer;

// The DataSource class
// Handles connecting/reconnecting to the data source, and piping endpoints together
(function() {
    "use strict";

    DataSource = function(net)
    {
        this.net = net;
    };

    DataSource.prototype.net = null;

    DataSource.prototype.host = 'localhost';
    DataSource.prototype.port = 0;
    DataSource.prototype.user = '';
    DataSource.prototype.pass = '';

    DataSource.prototype.socket = null;
    DataSource.prototype.currentClient = null;

    DataSource.prototype.start = function(host, port, user, pass)
    {
        if (host !== undefined) {
            this.host = host;
        }
        if (port !== undefined) {
            this.port = port;
        }
        if (user !== undefined) {
            this.user = user;
        }
        if (pass !== undefined) {
            this.pass = pass;
        }

        this.socket = this.net.createConnection(this.port, this.host);

        this.socket.on('connect', function () {
            console.log('Data source connected');

            this.socket.write(this.user + '@' + this.pass);
        }.bind(this));

        this.socket.on('error', function() {
            console.error('Error on data source connection');

            this.stop();
            this.start();
        }.bind(this));

        this.socket.on('end', function() {
            console.error('Data source connection terminated');

            this.stop();
            this.start();
        }.bind(this));
    };

    DataSource.prototype.stop = function()
    {
        this.socket.end();
        this.socket = null;
    };

    DataSource.prototype.attachClient = function(client)
    {
        console.log('Attaching client to data source');

        this.currentClient = client;

        this.socket.pipe(this.currentClient);
        this.currentClient.pipe(this.socket, {end: false});
    };

    DataSource.prototype.detachCurrentClient = function()
    {
        console.log('Detaching client from data source');

        this.socket.unpipe(this.currentClient);
        this.currentClient.unpipe(this.socket);

        this.currentClient = null;
    };

    DataSource.prototype.hasClient = function()
    {
        return this.currentClient !== null;
    };
}());

// The PHPClientServer class
// Handles the server operations for PHP clients
(function() {
    "use strict";

    PHPClientServer = function(net, dataSource)
    {
        this.net = net;
        this.dataSource = dataSource;

        this.pendingClientStack = [];
    };

    PHPClientServer.prototype.net = null;
    PHPClientServer.prototype.dataSource = null;

    PHPClientServer.prototype.host = null;
    PHPClientServer.prototype.port = null;

    PHPClientServer.prototype.server = null;
    PHPClientServer.prototype.pendingClientStack = null;

    PHPClientServer.prototype.start = function(host, port)
    {
        var clientTerminateHandler = function() {
            console.log('Client disconnected');
            this.dataSource.detachCurrentClient();

            if (this.pendingClientStack.length) {
                console.log('Attaching next client in queue');
                this.dataSource.attachClient(this.pendingClientStack.shift());
            }
        }.bind(this);

        if (host !== undefined) {
            this.host = host;
        }
        if (port !== undefined) {
            this.port = port;
        }

        this.server = this.net.createServer(function(client) {
            console.log('Client connected');

            client.on('end', clientTerminateHandler);
            client.on('error', clientTerminateHandler);

            if (this.dataSource.hasClient()) {
                console.log('Client added to queue');
                this.pendingClientStack.push(client);
            } else {
                this.dataSource.attachClient(client);
            }
        }.bind(this));

        this.server.listen(this.port, this.host);
    };

    PHPClientServer.prototype.stop = function()
    {
        this.server.close();
        this.server = null;
    };
}());

// Bootstrap
var net, dataSource, server;

net = require('net');

dataSource = new DataSource(net);
dataSource.start('192.168.0.1', 23);

server = new PHPClientServer(net, dataSource);
server.start('0.0.0.0', 12345);
```

I realise that's a wall of code with minimal explanation, so please ask if there's something you don't understand.

Also, before anyone says it, yes I am fully aware that I am treating a prototypical OOP language as if it were a classical one, Javascript != Java, yada yada yada. I don't care, I like to work with Javascript in this manner.

Comment: Man... beautyfull code! Very nice code... It didnt work.. return lot of warning of recursive things... then max stack exceed...but I'm trying to fix it... By the way... I dont need the stored data couse the data will never be the same

Comment: What .bind(this) does?

Comment: @FilipeTagliacozzi I wrote this shortly before I left the office for the day, on the way home I was thinking about it and I realised that this is probably not what you want to do. I'm going to rewrite it a bit later and update it to what I think you actually want (and test it this time, as well). [`.bind(this)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) ensures that callbacks are always executed in the correct context. An alternative is `var that = this;`. Both are ugly solutions to a problem that shouldn't exist in the first place.

Comment: Ok...Ill try to explain better: I need a service(A) that persist-connects to a data-server(B) via TCP/IP. At the same time create a server(C) that forms a bridge between the data-server(B) and the PHP clients(X,Y,Z) ... So those clients can request the data passing some parameters through the service(A) to server(B) then returns the data to clients(X,Y,Z)... waiting for your advices

Comment: @FilipeTagliacozzi When you say the PHP clients pass parameters through to the data server, how exactly do they do this? The real problem here is that a single persistent connection is difficult to share between multiple clients if they all need to extract different data. If they all need the same data then a simple "broadcast" type configuration is easy to do, but if they need different data then only one of them can access the service at a time - since the connection can only do one thing at a time

Comment: Yep.. maybe I have to write some FIFO handler

Comment: @FilipeTagliacozzi Have a go with the edited code above. I've adjusted it so that it simply queues clients and pipes one client at a time to the remote endpoint. I've tested it with a simple telnet server and it seems to work as expected, and as I think you want it to.

Comment: Awesome!!...  Tnx man... Ive learned a lot with your code. Beutyfully structured. Greetingss..